# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'stay'

Tags: php

This is my php code

```
<?php
if( $_POST )
{

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','','');

if (!$con)
{

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('stay', $con);

// escape variables for security

$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);

$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uemail']);

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']);

$rpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['urpass']);

echo $sql = "INSERT INTO reg(name,email,pass,rpass)VALUES ('$firstname', 
'$lastname', '$password','$rpassword')";

if (!$db_selected) 
{

    die ('Can\'t use stay : ' . mysql_error());

}

else
{

  mysql_query($sql,$con);

}

mysql_close($con);

}

?>
```

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ4Gr.jpg)

I want to perform insert operation using POST. The problem is of access 
to the database in phpMyAdmin named as stay. I am uploading the screen 
shot too.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` library, it is deprecated and removed from php7.0. Not even learning purpose. Use `mysqli_` or `pdo_` instead and add the username to the database. Default username is `root`

Comment: Use `mysqli_` and either you have to create a new user or use `root` user with correct password

Comment: Enter "root" as your username mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

Answer (score 0):

Your user cannot be blank in row

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','','');
```

Check it out, probbably it's 'root' if you have a newly installed xampp/wampp server

Answer (score 0):

1. In your line #5 you should type correct database username and password:

   ```
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','someusername','somepassword');
   ```
2. Don't use any mysql_* functions. They're deprecated. Use [MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) instead.